# evaluate next date and if the first friday of month echo that for me

Tags: bash

My try:

```
we=$(LC_TIME=C date +%A)
dm=$(date +%d)
wday="Friday"

            if [ "$we" = "$wday" ] && [ "$dm" -lt 8 ]
            then do some stuff
```

I means on first friday he make sume stuff. How can I store this in a variable, that if the next time is the first Friday in the month for an echo output.

Now the script executes me only on the first Friday in the month something.

It must be evaluate if the next friday is in the next month or not if yes do some. (Debian 11)

Comment: Which specific version of `date`? (It's provided by your operating system, not part of bash, so behavior differs; there are some relevant features that are GNUisms and not available on MacOS or other BSDs).

Comment: (...also, note that for the simple cases you can use something like `printf '%(%A)T\n' -1` and avoid using the external `date` command altogether, if you have a new enough version of bash).

Comment: I have linux debian 11. In this case if i use the script on last friday in month the output must be „ next date dd.mm.yy is the first friday of the new month. I tryed some different ways, but i dont come on that result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your OS is debian, I assume GNU `date` command which supports `-d` option
is available. Then would you please try the following:

```
dayofweek="$(date -d "tomorrow" +%u)"  # day of week (1..7); 1 is Monday
dayofmonth="$(date -d "tomorrow" +%d)" # day of month (e.g., 01)
if (( dayofweek == 5 && 10#$dayofmonth < 8 )); then
    # do some stuff
fi
```

- As the format `%u` prints the day of week between 1 and 7, you can compare
  it with 5 to detect Friday.
- The day of month includes the leading zero such as `01` and you need to
  convert it to a decimal digit number by prefixing `10#`. Otherwise
  the number with a leading zero is interpreted as octal then `08` and `09`
  will cause an error.